# Does soap clean grease because it lowers surface tension? Or are these things independent?

Tags: water, surface-tension

> Have you noticed how much easier it is to clean dirty, greasy hands or plates once you add soap to the water? By reducing the surface tension of water, soaps and detergents allow it to mix with oil and grease more easily. Warm water melts the oils and fats so that it is easier for the soap to work – that is why warm, soapy water is so effective.

Is this quote correct? I thought soap worked by connecting directly to grease by its hydrophobic parts, not by allowing water to mix with oil and grease due to reduced surface tension.

Comment: Warm water is more important for a quick action rather than from a quantitative point of view. Also they use loosely the term "melt". I don't write another answer which would be basically the same as that by niels nielsen plus the two lines above. Basically your last sentence is correct. Still reducing the surface tension makes water a better solvent for dirt in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soap has one end of its molecule which is soluble in water, while the other end is soluble in oily substances. This makes soap act like a glue that sticks oil molecules to water molecules, allowing the water to carry away the oil. In this way, soapy water will remove oily stains from fabric.

In addition, soap reduces the surface tension of the water, allowing it to enter small crevices more easily, which makes it more effective as a cleaning agent. So both effects are important, but the thing that gets grease off surfaces is the actions of the two different ends of the soap molecule.

Comment: Correct, so in this way, it's not **because** of the lowering of surface tension, correct? The quote seems to imply that.

Comment: reducing the surface tension of the water (with soap,  or a surfactant) allows it to enter small crevices more easily, which makes it more effective as a cleaning agent.

Comment: Correct again, but we agree that soap cleans grease not **because** it lowers surface tension, right? It helps, however.

Comment: Both effects are important, but the thing that gets grease off surfaces is the actions of the two different ends of the soap molecule.